# Is there a fast way to sell large amounts of ammo?

Tags: resident-evil-village

When playing Mercenaries, I sometimes play runs without certain guns. As a result I collect hundreds of bullets that I'd like to sell since I don't plan on firing them.

However, when adding up the bullets to sell by holding right on the stick, I have to count each bullet individually. This wastes a ton of time, especially since I need to do this at least 3 times a game and play multiple Mercenaries sessions back to back.

Is there a shortcut to sell all ammo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a shortcut to sell huge quantities of ammo at once, but there are some small things to make it faster.

Holding the D-Pad on a controller will increase or decrease the volume of ammo sold pretty fast already. [According to this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/theouterworlds/comments/dpco8u/console_gaming_tip_on_selling_massive_quantities/) you can hold both the D-Pad button and move the thumbstick to double the rate that the ammo is transferred. This trick can be replicated on PC by holding both the <kbd>D</kbd> key and holding down the transfer arrow using the mouse.

You still won't be able to sell stacks of ammo without stopping to select a different stack, but it should make it slightly less painful when you're trying to get rid of 2000 bullets.